# La aplicación se detiene al clickear un Button que abre una nueva Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy teniendo problemas con mi App android.
He programado un botón que al hacerle click abre una nueva Activity. Pero el problema es que cuando lo ejecuto en el emulador al hacer click en el botón la aplicación produce un crash, se detiene.

Este es el código

```
package com.flixarts.ar.preguntasyrespuestas;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PantallaBienvenida extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pantallabienvenida);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mostrarPantalla2Button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openActivity2();
        }
    });

}

public void openActivity2() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GenerarPreguntas.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

LOGCAT:

```
2018-12-12 14:53:43.710 2681-2681/com.flixarts.ar.preguntasyrespuestas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.flixarts.ar.preguntasyrespuestas, PID: 2681
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.flixarts.ar.preguntasyrespuestas/com.flixarts.ar.preguntasyrespuestas.GenerarPreguntas}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:56)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
    at com.flixarts.ar.preguntasyrespuestas.GenerarPreguntas.<init>(GenerarPreguntas.java:18)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: y cual es el error del logcat? o de la consola

Comment: Hola Igmer ahí puse el Logcat.. todavía no tengo mucha experiencia con los errores de Logcat

Comment: pero los errores hacen referencia a otras cosas no se si si hay algo en el oncreate del GenerarPreguntas

Comment: No toda la información que se registra en el LogCat es util, revisa específicamente en color rojo donde muestre el mensaje "Caused by" @MauroStancato , Por cierto que realiza GenerarPreguntas ?

Comment: GenerarPreguntas es el nombre de una activity, no es un método... gracias Jorgesys

Comment: @MauroStancato se que es una Activity pero me parece que realiza operaciones donde carga y reproduce multimedia, es así? Revisa en el LogCat con rojo donde diga "Caused by", puedes filtrar la información seleccionando como filtro : "Show only selected application".

Comment: Hola Jorge, no sé por qué apareció eso de sonido, la app es sólo de Buttons y textViews. Ahí subí el logcat con Show only selected application

Comment: Hola @MauroStancato que te parece si agregas a la pregunta el código de la actividad que intentas cargar. Tal vez si complementas esa parte podamos ver más a fondo cual sea el error. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que debes declarar la actividad dentro del archivo AndroidManifest.xml de esta manera

```
<manifest ... >
    <application ... >
       <activity android:name=".ExampleActivity" />
       ...
    </application ... >
    ...
</manifest >
```

Y si eso lo tienes hecho puedes reemplazar

> `public void openActivity2() {
>       Intent intent = new Intent(this, GenerarPreguntas.class);
>       startActivity(intent);
>   }`

Por

```
public void openActivity2(){
 Intent mainIntent = new Intent(PantallaBienvenida.this, GenerarPreguntas.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            PantallaBienvenida.this.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberías revisar si cada `Activity` está ligada a su respectivo `Layout`, después de eso, checa si le botón que estás casteando se encuentra efectivamente en `R.layout.pantallabienvenida`